# Animate/translate view from position of other view

Tags: android, animation

I have a fab and a framelayout which can host a fragment.

I'm trying to do a translation animation so that my framelayout starts at the position of the fab and ends up at its original position. (complex layout, the fab is in another xml file but `<include>` in same layout as the frame) So basically step 2 here: [How to transform a FAB into a popup menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058162/how-to-transform-a-fab-into-a-popup-menu)

I have tried:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="340"
    android:fromYDelta="431"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

and

```
val anim = TranslateAnimation(340f, 0f, 431f, 0f)
```

with

```
 myFab.setOnClickListener {
    val frame = my_frame_im_about_to_fill_with_a_fragment
    frame.startAnimation(anim)
 }
```

So I tried with the values I get from these methods

```
myFab.getLocationOnScreen()
myFab.getLocationInWindow()
```

Both methods give `(891, 1130)`. I've tried plugging those in or converting it to dp, that gets it closer(not very close still though).

Another strange thing is that I thought if I used absolute values in the animation I thought zero would be top left of the screen but it isn't. `x: 0 y: 0` give me the same results as `0%,0%` and `0%p,0%p`. they all animate the view to the top left point of where the framelayout is in constrained to in the xml

How do I translate a view from another view to 'itself'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ConstraintLayout for your layout, put your view constraints to starting position (here I will animate `@+id/view` after clicking `@+id/fab`. Animated view has to be `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE` - `GONE` will mess up animation.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
             /*constraint stuff*/>       
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/symbolList" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

There are few options:

1. Use ObjectAnimator

In your xml file put View that will be animated on fab position:

```
view = findViewById(R.id.view)
fab = findViewById(R.id.fab)

fab.setOnClickListener {

    view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val propertyX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.X, 0f)
    val propertyY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.Y, 0f)
    ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, propertyX, propertyY).apply {
        duration = 2000L
        start()
    }
}
```

2. Or use ViewPropertyAnimator (same XML as above)

   ```
       fab.setOnClickListener {
         view.animate()
               .x(0f)
               .y(0f)
               .setDuration(2000L)
               .start()
       }
   ```
3. Or use TransitionManager, MotionLayout, scene api or animate ConstraintSet manually.

   ```
   private fun startAnimation() {

   val animationEndConstraints = ConstraintSet().apply {
       clone(container)
       clear(button.id, ConstraintSet.START)
       clear(button.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
       // instead of parent you can use fab.id
       connect(button.id, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 0)
       connect(button.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)
   }
   TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(container)
   animationEndConstraints.applyTo(container)
   }
   ```

This approach will allow to specify start state as xml layout and end state as xml layout, but you will have less control.

With other view position:

```
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            view.animate()
                .x(fab.left.toFloat())
                .y(fab.top.toFloat())
                .setDuration(2000L)
                .start()
        }
```

Comment: Hmm havn't tried yet, but I don't get your xml setup? It can probably be cleaned up to give a clearer answer

Comment: Just place view to be animated on starting position in your layout and animate to destination.

Comment: Yes, it will be top left corner.

Comment: Hmm ok then its a problem. I want the animation to go from one point to another, neither of which is top left corner of the screen. In my example (0,0) was the origin/anchor of my view (your solution involve moving the view to the FAB so then moving to 0,0 doesn't make sense and the view needs to move to some coordinate/anchor view where I'd want it to go... but then again... that is my problem, those coordinates does not seem to be correct)

Comment: But I havn't had time to try out the ObjectAnimator/ViewPropertyAnimator in my use case yet, so maybe that'll fix it

Comment: I've added example how get target x and y position. Also in 3. there is sample how animate using constraints.